# Implementing a set template in c++ adding and removing

Tags: c++, set

I need to create an add and remove function for a SET data structure without using the STL for C++ here is the .h code and I need to write out the code to implement the functions in the .h code. This is a templated class that will be used in inheriting its properties into a larger scope project. While I understand there isn't much to go off of I would really appreciate the help because this is all of the instructions I was simply given.

```
template <class T>
class Set {
public:
Set();
Set(const Set<T> & other); //copy constructor that makes a deep copy
~Set(); //destructor
void add (const T & item); //Adds the item to the set
void remove (const T & item); //Removes the item from the set
}
```

If someone could please point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: What kind of set would like to implement? Set is a data structure behavioral pattern and can be implemented using different kinds of trees, arrays, etc... Depending on the implementation complexity and your goals

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: So the instructions are as follows "create and implement a template Set data type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple direction: have a look at the implementation of set and map in STL. Also read something about binary search trees(if you need to implement something of the same complexity as `std::set`) and especially red-black trees. Another option is to use a hash map.